# Business location dataset

Tags: geolocation, directory, location, yellow-pages

I'm looking for a good dataset of business locations, hopefully for all of the USA.  I'd love to have "name," "business type," and "lat/long," although I'd settle for "street address" rather than "lat/long," and I could geocode the points myself.

Are there any free or relatively cheap data sources for business locations?  Can I get this information from google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to settle for yelp dataset. It seems to be the closest to what you are looking for. You'll need to be associated with an academic institution to qualify for access though. Check out this link : http://www.yelp.com/academic_dataset